# How to handle date in an international website

Tags: javascript, database, date, server, client

I'm developping a website with user from different countries. I have difficulties to understand how to handle date so that I can do comparison of date coming from different country and stored in the database and and so that I can display these dates in the right local to the browser.

From my understanding I need to convert date sent to the server to ISO 8601 format that is `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sTZD` format using `toISOString()` method in javascript.

Then on the server data is stored in ISO 8601 format and when sent to the browser let it do the handling to convert from ISO 8601 format to local fomat to display to the user.

Am I on the right track ? I'm a bit confused because I see some articles explaining that we have to use UTC format when sending date to the server.

Thanks for any explanations.

Comment: [toISOString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) actually is in UTC.

Comment: In general you are on the right track. But it also depends on how you store the date on your backend. Usually you should not store it as a string but in the respective date type of your database. So you might have to convert it to that first.

Comment: this documentation [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) tells me it is in ISO 8601 and if it's in UTC what is the difference with toUTCString()

Comment: ISO 8601 is a specification of a date format, UTC is a time zone. `toUTCString` returns a *human-readable* date time string in UTC. `toUTCString` used to be implementation-dependant up to and including [ES2017](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-date.prototype.toutcstring). In [ES2018](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-date.prototype.toutcstring), however, the format *is* defined. But not every browser properly implements ES2018 yet.

Comment: @str—not to be picky, but UTC is a time standard, not a time zone. ;-)